# Excel macro to move rows based on cell criteria without moving the formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting, vba

I'm using the following macro to move rows from one sheet to another. This part works like a charm. What I'm trying to figure out is how to do this without affecting my conditional formatting.

```
Sub MoveCompleted()

    Dim h As Variant
    Dim endrow As Integer
    Dim OL As Worksheet, Cmp As Worksheet

    Set OL = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Open_Log")
    Set Cmp = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Completed")

    endrow = OL.Range("A" & OL.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For h = 2 To endrow
        If OL.Cells(h, "H").Value = "COMPLETE" Then
           OL.Cells(h, "H").EntireRow.Cut Destination:=Cmp.Range("A" & Cmp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I have images to post including my formatting but my rep is too low on this site to post them.

Quick example:

before running macro the "Applies to" looks like: `=$A$12:$I$100000`
after running the macro it looks like: `=$A$12:$I$63,$A$68:$I$100000`

leaving the gap(s) where the previously moved rows were.

Comment: post link to your uploaded image to some sharing site like dropbox, then someone can attach those with your question.

Comment: Are you trying to preserve the conditional formatting in the TARGET, Or the SOURCE row?

Comment: I'm trying to keep the formatting from "Open_Log" on "Open_Log" and I want the formatting on "Completed" to not be changed since it differs from how "Open_Log" is formatted. Also, thanks for the quick responses

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way short of resetting the conditional formatting after the move. (Issue has been mentioned a few times on SO before).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to reconsider what you are trying to do by going about it in a slightly different way.

Instead of REMOVING the whole row, you could just clear it.

Also, instead of copying the whole row, you could set the values for each cell very easily with a loop.  That would preserve the formatting in the cell.  I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but I'm all in favor of showing people how to run simple loops, instead of recording cut and paste from macros.

Try putting this bit of code into what you already have going.

```
LastCompletedRow = Sheets("Completed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Sheets("Open_Log").Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column     'Get the last column on the source.

    For h = 2 To endrow
        If OL.Cells(h, "H").Value = "COMPLETE" Then
           For col = 1 To LastCol
               Sheets("Completed").Cells(LastCompletedRow, col).Value = Sheets("Open_Log").Cells(h, col).Value
               Sheets("Open_Log").Cells(h, col).Value = ""    'Clear the original cell you just copied.
           Next col
        End If
    Next
```